# McAfee TIE Write Only Master (WOM) not able to register in ePO

Tags: configuration, mcafee

We have 2 WOM, 2 Reporter, 2 Slave server for for an installation. During OVF deployment and initial configuration, only IP was configured and rest of the server setting have been configured using pre-built scriptlets.

Issue Facing:

1. When slave is configured with WOM as Master, it is showing a message as "pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: server does not support ssl, but ssl was required" as a result getting an error as "initctl: Job failed to start"

Note: (WOM are configured to allow connection to Postgre DB from Reporter, Slave)

2. When we restart the tieserver services using "service tieserver restart"and tieservers pg services using "service tieserver pg_start", tiesever service as well as PostgreSQL service does not start, even after trying several times
3. Also, none of these servers are getting registered in ePO as "Managed" with Tag as "TIESERVER"

Please suggest the way forward to rectify the issue with TIE installation.

Thanks.